# import "Sympy" couldn't be resolved

Tags: python, sympy

[Line:3 Import "sympy" couldn't be resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWDwm.png)

I have installed sympy using pip in my virtual environment.
Why am I getting this error? When I run this code I am am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x:\path\NumericalMethods.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sympy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
```

Here are the modules that are installed:

```
altgraph==0.17
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
future==0.18.2
mpmath==1.2.1
numpy==1.20.3
openpyxl==3.0.7
panda3d==1.10.9
pandas==1.2.4
pefile==2019.4.18
pyinstaller==4.3
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.1
PyQt5==5.15.4
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.9.0
PyQt5Designer==5.14.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
six==1.16.0
sympy==1.8
unit-converter==1.1.0
xlrd==2.0.1
```

Comment: Let me know which editor are you using or any IDE?

Comment: I am using VS Code

Comment: Yes then great I have solution

Comment: Have you tried using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/)? It most probably will solve your import problem and also `sympy` comes pre-installed.

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment? can you make sure if the vscode is using the correct python environment you have set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to check whether you are running the code in the virtual environment, to verify that refer the below image

[image: VS Code Env]

> If you are not in a virtual environment that you have created just
> click that red box that I have marked in that pic and select the
> respective virtual environment Interpreter (python.exe).

Answer (score 0):

Some IDE's have virtual environments. If so, you can't just open cmd, but you need to find the terminal that comes from your IDE to install librarys